# Wordpress menu issue after update

Tags: menus, sub-menu, backup, css

**INHERITED WEBSITE** - I'm taking over an existing Wordpress website ([prepwellness.org](http://prepwellness.org/)) and I noticed several things wrong with the Wordpress GUI.

1) It didn't have a "Posts" option in the left navigation pane. 
2) It was an antiquated version of Wordpress.

**UPDATING WORDPRESS - BIG MISTAKE** - I decided to update the old version of Wordpress and now the main top menu is not at all what it used to be as far as styles is concerned.

NEW MENU ISSUE - For some reason, the default main top menu is stuck as one of the footer menus (footer1), even after I select and save the "main" menu as the default menu within the "Menus" link under the "Appearance" section of the left navigation pane. I also tried to change the menu from the footer menu to the main menu in the Appearance > Customize > Menus option with no luck.

Any suggestions as to how I can fix that?

**ORIGINAL WEBSITE VERSION STYLES** - The attached image below is what the original version of the website main top menu looked like in the original version of Wordpress before the Wordpress update to a newer version. The main menu should have a blue background, 7 main links and multiple hidden sub-links under each main link which display after hovering over a main link.

**FEEBLE ATTEMPTS** - I've tried creating a new menu and setting that menu as the default for the top main menu without any luck.

I altered the main style.css file within the theme with no luck. It had disabled many styles, including the blue background. That didn't work.

I've scoured the php files within the editor, but because I'm a novice at php, I didn't do much in there.

**BACKED UP FOLDERS** - I backed up the database, content, etc, but am not sure it would revert everything back to the original look with the new version of Wordpress.

Any suggestions are welcom. 
Your time is appreciated.

~ Czach
[image: This image is what the original version of the website main top menu looked like.]

Comment: Your best bet is to walk through the theme and exam how things were built. The "posts" post type can be turned off and the menu could be built in many different ways. You can also turn on [debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to help you troubleshoot issues. One thing I can point out by looking at the source code is that the main navigation is tagged as "menu-footer-1" which indicates that's the wrong menu.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest going through all options of the Theme Customization to setup (and understand) everything. Check the Menu area to make sure that the theme is selecting the proper menu. Look at the Menus that are defined to ensure you are selecting the correct menu.

Some themes use 'widget areas' to allow for different content (including menus) in those areas. Looking at all areas of theme customization is a good place to start.

It may be that plugins are affecting things. Take a look at all plugins to determine their 'worth'. Update everything to the latest version (WP, themes, plugins). Get rid of old/unused themes/plugins.

If you need information, the googles will usually get you started. But wandering through every option on the WP Admin menu is good for understanding.